# Asp.net core HTTP 500 ERROR When TemData.Keep() is Used

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

**CityController**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using MVC.Models;

namespace MVC.Controllers
{
    public class CityController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<CityController> _logger;

        public CityController(ILogger<CityController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult CitiesOnMap()
        {

            List<City> cities = new List<City>();

           cities.Add(new City { CityName = "Hatay", Latitude = 123, Longtitude = 435 });
           cities.Add(new City { CityName = "Konya", Latitude = 123, Longtitude = 435 });
           cities.Add(new City { CityName = "Istanbul", Latitude = 123, Longtitude = 435 });
           cities.Add(new City { CityName = "Izmir", Latitude = 123, Longtitude = 435 });
           cities.Add(new City { CityName = "Samsun", Latitude = 123, Longtitude = 435 });
           cities.Add(new City { CityName = "Antalya", Latitude = 123, Longtitude = 435 });
           cities.Add(new City { CityName = "Bursa", Latitude = 123, Longtitude = 435 });
           cities.Add(new City { CityName = "Manisa", Latitude = 123, Longtitude = 435 });
           cities.Add(new City { CityName = "Mersin", Latitude = 123, Longtitude = 435 });
           cities.Add(new City { CityName = "Ankara", Latitude = 123, Longtitude = 435 });
  
           TempData["cities"] = cities;
           return View(); 
        }

       
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult CitiesOnMap(string SelectedCity)
        {

            if (TempData["cities"] != null)
            {
                foreach (var redirectedCity in TempData["cities"] as List<City>)
                {
                    
                    if (String.Equals(redirectedCity.CityName, SelectedCity))
                    {

                        TempData["selectedCity"] = redirectedCity;
                        return RedirectToAction(redirectedCity.CityName, "City");
                    }


                }
            }


            return RedirectToAction(SelectedCity, "City"); ;
        }




        public IActionResult Hatay()
        {
            return View();
        }



        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

In my index page, there is a dropdown to choose a map. User choose a map and click the button and after that I used RedirectToAction to redirect CitiesOnMap.cshtml with this CityController.

**CitiesOnMap.cshtml**

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "CitiesOnMap";
}



<div class="text-center pt-5">
    <h1 class="display-4 pb-2 ">LET'S SEE THE CITIES!</h1>
    <p class="pb-3">Now, Please Choose A City You Want to See on Map.</p>
    <h3> @TempData["SelectedMap"] </h3>

    <div class="text-center mx-auto pt-5">
        <form asp-action="CitiesOnMap" asp-controller="City" method="post">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-9 mx-auto">
                    <select id="drpEmpList" name="SelectedCity" class="form-control">
                        <option disabled selected hidden>Choose a City </option>

                        @foreach (var name in TempData["cities"] as List<MVC.Models.City>)
                        {

                            <option>@name.CityName </option>
                        }
                        
                    </select>
                    

                    <input type="hidden" />

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 pt-4">

                    <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Let's See" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" />
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm sending cities list that is the classes of my City model. On this page, user is choosing a city from a dropdown on CitiesOnMap.cshtml file. After choosing, I want to redirect user to the proper city page. But when the user select submit button, if I don't use TempData["cities"].Keep() method, .net throws an NullReferenceError because I can't keep my data again after using it as far as I know. If I use TempData["cities"].Keep() method, ı receive HTTP 500 ERROR. And also I think i have to serialize my TempData["cities"] but I'm so confused I have so many problems:( Please help me

Comment: HTTP 500 -> Internal Server Error -> look at logs for an unhandled exception

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto How can i do it? I'm beginner level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly,your code makes a mistake that you **cannot pass** `TempData["KeyName"]` **redirect to another controller action**. Otherwise it will return 500 error with the following error message.That is because `TempData` uses `Session`, which itself uses `IDistributedCache`. `IDistributedCache` doesn't have the capability to accept objects or to serialize objects:

```
InvalidOperationException: The 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.TempDataSerializer' cannot serialize an object of type ....
```

Here is a working demo by using JSON.Net(you could also use System.Text.Json):

```
public IActionResult CitiesOnMap()
{

    List<City> cities = new List<City>();
    //....
    cities.Add(new City { CityName = "Ankara", Latitude = 123, Longtitude = 435 });
    //Serialize manually by JSON.Net....        
    TempData["cities"] = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cities);  
    TempData.Keep("cities");  
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult CitiesOnMap(string SelectedCity)
{
    if (TempData["cities"] != null)
    {
        foreach (var redirectedCity in JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<City>>(TempData["cities"] as string))
        {
            if (String.Equals(redirectedCity.CityName, SelectedCity))
            {
                //not sure what is your selected city page
                //but if you redirect to another action
                //you also need to serialize the model data manually
                TempData["selectedCity"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(redirectedCity);                
                return RedirectToAction(redirectedCity.CityName, "City");
            }
        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction(SelectedCity, "City"); ;
}
```

CitiesOnMap.cshtml:

```
<form asp-action="CitiesOnMap" asp-controller="City" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-9 mx-auto">
            <select id="drpEmpList" name="SelectedCity" class="form-control">
                <option disabled selected hidden>Choose a City </option>

                @foreach (var name in         
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MVC.Models.City>>(TempData["cities"] as string))
                {
                    <option>@name.CityName </option>
                }

            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Oh my god thank you soooo much. But can i ask one more question? I redirected to the proper city page but here, how can I use the TempData["selectedCity"] object into my city view? I tried something but I got "cannot deserialize" error :(

Here is my city view:
```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "CitiesOnMap";
    var selectedCity = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MVC.Models.City>(TempData["cities"] as string);
}


    <h3>Selected City: @selectedCity.CityName </h3>
```

Comment: Hi @Mertcan, did you modify in backend:`TempData["selectedCity"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(redirectedCity);`? Also, in the frontend, it is `TempData["selectedCity"]` but you use `TempData["cities"] `.

Comment: lool I'm sorry yeah I Just changed the cities as selectedCity and fixed. Really really thank you so much I've been suffering these errors since yesterday:(