# Trying to add comments to database

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Hi I'm a programmer at aspnetcore mvc and I'm trying to add comments to the database,
In my project there are a certain amount of animals and I want each animal to be allowed to add comments according to its id.

My Comment Model:

```
public Comment()
    {
        Animal = new Animal();
    }
    [Key]
    public int CommentId { get; set; }
    public int AnimalId { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; } = null!;

    [ForeignKey("AnimalId")]
    [InverseProperty("Comments")]
    public virtual Animal Animal { get; set; } = null!;
```

My Animal Model:

```
public Animal()
    {
        Comments = new HashSet<Comment>();
        //Category = new Category();
    }
    [Key]
    public int AnimalId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Birth Date")]
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(200)]
    [Display(Name = "Portrait")]
    public string PhotoUrl { get; set; } = null!;

    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    //[InverseProperty("Category")]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; } = null!;
    //[InverseProperty("Animal")]
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller&action(get,post):

```
public IActionResult Indexx()
    {
        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Indexx([Bind("Content")] Comment comment)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(comment);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Indexx));
        }
        return View(comment);
    }
```

My View:
@model PetShop.Data.Models.Comment

```
<form action="Indexx2" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Content" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Content" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Content" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
<input type="submit" value="click me"/>
```

Validation:

```
@section Scripts {
@{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before giving solution, I need note you that make property nullable if you use **.NET 6**. Otherwise it will fail for model validation.

For Example, change the property below:

```
public string PhotoUrl { get; set; } = null!;
```

To:

```
public string? PhotoUrl { get; set; }
```

Here is a whole working demo:

View:

```
@model Comment

<form method="post">
    <select asp-items="ViewBag.Animal" asp-for="AnimalId"></select>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Content" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Content" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Content" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="click me"/>
</form>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    ViewData["Animal"] = new SelectList(_context.Animal.ToList(), "AnimalId", "Name");
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index([Bind("Content,AnimalId")] Comment comment)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var animal = await _context.Animal.FindAsync(comment.AnimalId);
        comment.Animal = animal;
        _context.Add(comment);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View(comment);
}
```

Comment: Yes it helped me but I ran into another problem as a result
I want in addition to that also to display on the same page the comments I uploaded on this post separately I would happy if you take a look

Comment: Your issue is caused by null exception. Be sure your Model contains value, if it does not contains value you cannot use foreach, you can add an if condition to judge if the Model==null or not outside the foreach loop.

Comment: But what I did was I divided the part into the partial view part of the model
And the part of the list in view is ok? @Rena

Comment: The partial view should be invoked like:`@await Html.PartialAsync("_MyPatial", new Comment())`. And for the null exception I think it can make such mistake caused by your main view. Because your main view you use foreach loop, if the model is null, it will throw null exception.  And your partial view just contain a input element, there is not any place will make null exception.

Comment: I have no option in view to make a new Comment
Regarding the test @if (Model! = Null)
I'm not making a mistake probably but I also want to solve the problem I need to fix my controller and move it to a list?

Comment: Got it，when you add the comment and redirect to action `Index1`,  you never return view with model in this action. So it will always be null for your main view model. If you just want to display the added new comment, you can use session or tempdata to store the added comment. Refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68841493/11398810. If you want to display all the comments together with the new comment, you can return view with model like: `return View(_context.Comment.ToList())`.

Comment: **return View(_context.Comment.ToList())** is not help my to solve my problem i got same error @Rena

Comment: Be sure `_context.Comment.ToList()` is not null..... I think you need debug your code to see which line makes null exception now.